# Momentjs with Meteor doesn't seem to work on server side

Tags: meteor, momentjs

I'm using the momentjs:moment package in my meteor project. Client side the `moment(new Date())` call works great. If I do the same call on the server side or if I wrap the same call in `console.log(moment(new Date()));` I get the error at the bottom of this question.

If I run `meteor shell` and then `moment(new Date());` I also get an error (`moment is not defined`). But if, from the shell, I wrap this in a `console.log(moment(new Date()));` it works fine and prints out to the console.

Any idea what I'm forgetting or what I'm not doing right here?

```
W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR) TypeError: Property 'moment' of object #<Object> is not a function
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object._.extend.send_donation_email (app/server/methods/mandrill.js:37:25)
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Stripe_Events.charge.succeeded (app/server/lib/stripe_events.js:55:23)
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Router.route.where (app/both/router/router.js:238:48)
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at boundNext (packages/iron:middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:121:1
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].urlencodedParser (/Users/Bechard/.meteor/packages/iron_router/.1.0.7.1oysnq2++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:69:27)
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:277:1
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].hookWithOptions (packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:276:1)
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at boundNext (packages/iron:middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
    W20150318-19:55:45.885(-5)? (STDERR)     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
```

**Update: Meteor 1.1 still having this issue. **

I have narrowed in on the reason it seems to work, then stop working. If I get my app to run into an error, without catching it then moment will stop working.

To test this I started Meteor, then the Meteor Shell and moment(), it worked. I then got my app to make a call to a non-existent function, which always throws something like the below error. Then I ran moment() from the Meteor Shell again and this time moment() doesn't work. Event if I restart Meteor it still doesn't work. I have restarted the computer and still, it doesn't work.

```
(STDERR) TypeError: Property 'customer.source.updated' of object #<Object> is not a function
W20150401-13:46:11.812(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Router.route.where (app/both/router/router.js:254:48)
W20150401-13:46:11.812(-5)? (STDERR)     at boundNext (packages/iron:middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
W20150401-13:46:11.812(-5)? (STDERR)     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
W20150401-13:46:11.812(-5)? (STDERR)     at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:121:1
W20150401-13:46:11.812(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].urlencodedParser (/Users/Bechard/.meteor/packages/iron_router/.1.0.7.1oysnq2++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:69:27)
W20150401-13:46:11.812(-5)? (STDERR)     at packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:277:1
W20150401-13:46:11.812(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
W20150401-13:46:11.812(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].hookWithOptions (packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:276:1)
W20150401-13:46:11.812(-5)? (STDERR)     at boundNext (packages/iron:middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
W20150401-13:46:11.813(-5)? (STDERR)     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
```

Comment: I'm not experiencing this issue with `momentjs:moment` and 1.0.4.1, but I've sometimes had success with changing the sequence of packages in the `packages` file. Each package ought to declare its dependencies, but never the less...

Answer (score 3):

I spent way too long working this exact issue today. I had just updated to Meteor 1.0.4.1 when I got stuck with this issue (although for me, the problem was that moment-range couldn't find `moment` in order to extend it). Try reverting back to Meteor 1.0.3.2 and see if the problem still persists.

UPDATE:

I just upgraded Meteor to 1.0.5, and the issue may have gone away for me. If you try upgrading your own apps, please post below if it resolves the issue for you as well. Thanks!

Comment: yea and because this package is integrated directly into the momentjs package I don't see where to file an issue on github. Have you tried reverting? I found a workaround in my system, but eventually I am going to need this to work. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have reverted to 1.0.3.2 for now. And you're totally right, momentjs hasn't made the actual meteor package public, which is bonkers...

Comment: Actually, they seem to have their meteor package wrapped into their core repo: https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/meteor -- so we should address the issue with them there.

Comment: My workaround was basically setting a static date. It won't work in production, but my production release is a couple of weeks out so I figured it would be addressed by then. Thanks for creating the issue, I wasn't sure the momentjs team would address any Meteor issues, otherwise I'd have done that

Comment: UPDATE:

I just upgraded Meteor to 1.0.5, and the issue may have gone away for me. If you try upgrading your own apps, please post below if it resolves the issue for you as well. Thanks!

Comment: No. It seems like it goes away, but if an uncaught error hits the server it stops working. Even after restarting the app it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was a bug in the way that Meteor was reloading itself in the shell environment and is fixed in Meteor 1.2.  For the relevant bug fix information, you can Git Commit [2e43a9](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/da87051f3498f3b121b66d38d7d6d970052e43a9) and [ae8395](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/8a578e954b0a31a5e0418b42bfbb37399aae8395) or [Meteor Issue #4010](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4010) or [#4109](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4109).

[MomentJS Issue 2285](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2285) tracked this issue.